# how to create ticket ID (combine string and increment Integer) in Flask Python

Tags: python, html, sqlite, flask, ticket-system

i want to create Ticketing System using Python flask and stored in SQlite, but i have trouble when storing the ticket id. i'm expect the ticket id will be (Datetime+"increment number"). the picture as below
[expectation view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pVvo1.png)

herewith the **views.py** file

```
#define ticketid

now = datetime.now()
formatted_date = str(now.strftime('%Y%m%d'))
dated = formatted_date 
tiket = [dated+str(i) for i in range(5)]

# To submit and create the ticket

@main.route('/submit', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def ticket():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        customer = request.form['customer']
        pic = request.form['pic']
        date = request.form['date']
        time = request.form['time']
        category = request.form['category']
        description = request.form['description']
        ticketid = tiket
        Connection = sqlite3.connect('D:\\my_app\\db\\customer.db')
        cursor = Connection.cursor()
        query1 = "INSERT INTO customer (customer, pic, date, time, category, description, ticketid) VALUES ('{customer}','{pic}','{date}','{time}','{category}','{description}','{ticketid}')".format(customer = customer, 
        pic = pic, date = date, time = time, category = category, description = description , ticketid = ticketid)
        cursor.execute(query1)
        Connection.commit()
        return redirect('/')
    else:
        return render_template('createTicket.html')
```

when i'm input the field in html, i got an error message

> sqlite3.OperationalError: near "202103100": syntax error

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: How do you have ticketId defined in your table?  if its an integer your query won't work

Comment: VARCHAR @JD2775

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try this.

```
 query1 = (f'INSERT INTO customer (customer, pic, date, time, category, description, ticketid) VALUES ("{customer}","{pic}","{date}","{time}","{category}","{description}","{ticketid}")')
```